# how to extract song name currently playing in any music player in android

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

[image]

```
IntentFiLter iF IntentFiLter();
iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.Peal.IMP.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.Pdio.andPoid.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayeP.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.andPew.apollo.metachanged");

registerReceiver(mReceiveP, iF);
```

The Problem is when I first open app it doesn't show the song's name. But now when the app is opened and next song is played it displays the name correctly. Something needs to be done when I first open the app so it automatically gets current song playing.

Please help

Comment: please don't post screenshots of code. Just copy the code format it as code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering an `IntentFilter` to receive broadcasts of the different music players. Whenever a song started (as in starts to play), the music players broadcast this information. When your app starts, the current song is already playing (as in started to play before app start), so there is no broadcast for it.

You could create a `Service` that is registered to the BroadcastIntent that stores the song info into e.g. SharedPrefs for your app to retrieve when starting.

Comment: I'll be using the service that is registered to the BroadcastIntent that stores the song info. But that service needs to be running all the time. how to do that?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html might be a good point to start. It does not need to running all the time. With the broadcast receiver the os will awaken it on the relevant broadcast events

Comment: so you are saying as soon as some media player will broadcast, my service will automatically starts ? which type of service i have to use, can you be specific, please